# Connecting Hive remote server from Python

Tags: python, hadoop, hive

I have a trouble connecting to hive running on remote server through my python script.
I'm using the same script (With different server details, of course) to connect to hive running on my localhost & am able to connect.

I'm starting the server on local host from command line with a command:

```
hive —service hiveserver2
```

That start the server and I run the python script

**Script to connect to Hive running on local host:**

```
import pyhs2    
conn = pyhs2.connect(host='localhost', port=10000, authMechanism='PLAIN', user='hive', password ='', database='default')
    with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute("show databases")
            for i in cur.fetch():
                print i
```

Using above code, am able to access db @ Hive on local host.

I'm using below code to connect to remote server, here I'm ***not*** doing anything on command line to start the remote server.

**Script to connect to Hive running on the remote server:**

```
conn = pyhs2.connect(host='<my remote server Ip>', port=<port no>, authMechanism='PLAIN', user='<usernameToConnectToRemoteServer>', password ="<remoteServerPassword>"  database='default')
with conn.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("show databases")
        for i in cur.fetch():
            print i
```

and this returns me a message:

> thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes.

I've tried to google & find the solution, as much as i can, but all I see are the examples to connect to local host. please help me resolve this.

Comment: Can you manually connect to that server with these credentials? (E.g. via ssh)

Comment: @Ashalynd Yes, am able to connect using SSH .

Comment: Could a a firewall issue - are you sure that your server allows incoming connections on port 10000? and that the network policy "knows" about port 10000 being used by a legitimate application?

Comment: Did you try connecting from your PC with a "normal" JDBC tool, such as SquirrelSQL or DBVisualizer?

Comment: Did you try connecting from your SSH console, using `beeline` command-line utility?

Comment: Did you check that your JDBC driver version is compatible with the HS2 version on the remote host??? Typically, you can't use a recent driver with an older server.

Comment: If it's a network / firewall issue, you should try to define an "SSH tunnel" from your PC to the remote machine --  i.e. you open a tunnel with PuTTY between local port 20000 and remote port 10000, then you connect to *local* port 20000, and PuTTY forwards the TCP packets inside your "tunnel".

Comment: If it's a version compatibility issue and you are using the Apache driver, find the correct JAR on the server (i.e. `hive-jdbc-***-standalone.jar`) and use it on your PC.

Comment: I'm able to SSH from Commandline. Remote server is on a different port (not 10000, but 45). Will check if JDBC driver is compatible with HS2 version.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing SSH to your remote machine and then connect to hive like below-

```
import paramiko
import traceback

def hive_query_executor():
dns_name = ''
conn_obj = paramiko.SSHClient()
conn_obj.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
try:
    conn_obj.connect(dns_name, username="hadoop",
                     key_filename='')# or password

    Hive_query="select * from abc limit 10;"
    query_execute_command = 'ihive -e "' + impala_query + '"'
    std_in, std_out, std_err = conn_obj.exec_command(query_execute_command)

    conn_obj.close()

except:
    print "Error :" + str(traceback.format_exc())
    exit(0)


hive_query_executor()
```